# expo cli warning: 'unrecognised event type: transformer_load_started

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm getting a weird warning when I start newly created expo projects using expo init and expo start. The project loads and I am able to work, but I get this warning:

```
Unrecognized event: {"type":"transformer_load_started"}
Unrecognized event: {"type":"transformer_load_done"}
```

I have no idea what this means or what caused this. When I load up older projects using expo start, I do not get this error.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue with just a simple project.

With some experimentation, I found that it caused by my Expo version which is `"expo": "^45.0.0"` in `packages.json`

Initializing your new projects with `Expo SDK 44` by using this command should fix the issue:

`expo init --template blank@44.0`

Maybe it will be fixed in a `Expo SDK 45` update.

EDIT:

I updated expo-cli to the last version (`5.4.12`) with `npm install -g expo-cli`  and it fixed the issue with Expo 45.